# CHAR(4) did not show FOUR CHAR in Table Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, char, sql-server-2008-r2

Okay the title cannot explain the situation correct enough.
Now this is it,
I have a table with columns

```
Table1
Columns0, CHAR(20), NOT NULL.
Columns1, CHAR(4), Allow Nulls.
Data : 'ARR '

Table2
Columns0, CHAR(20), NOT NULL.
Columns1, CHAR(4), NOT NULL.
Data : 'ARR '
```

Then I join two tables together.

```
SELECT (ISNULL(a.Columns1,'') + ISNULL(b.Columns1,'')) AS WhatEver
FROM Table1 a 
left join Table2 b on a.Columns0 = b.Columns0
```

The result should appear as `'ARR ARR '`
instead of this, it appear as `'ARRARR '`

Why does this happen?

---

EDIT 2012/06/11:

After struggling, I ended up doing things like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(4),a.Columns1),'') + ISNULL(b.Columns1,'')
```

Then only I get correct result `'ARR ARR '`

But I am pretty sure my data type is `CHAR(4)` in the database.

Thank guys..

---

EDIT 2012/08/06:

Another solution that I found working is to change the TABLE 2 COLUMN 1 to (CHAR(4), NULL).
This can be done through 
ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY [column_name] [column_data_type] [null|not null]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works fine on my server (SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
create table SOxx1
(
    col1  char(4),
    col2  char(20) not null
)

create table SOxx2
(
    col1  char(4),
    col2  char(20) not null
)
Go

insert into SOxx1 (col1, col2) VALUES ('ARR ', 'abc')
insert into SOxx2 (col1, col2) VALUES ('ARR ', 'abc')
go

SELECT (ISNULL(a.col1,'') + ISNULL(b.col1,'')) AS WhatEver 
FROM SOxx1 a  
left join SOxx2 b on a.Col2 = b.Col2

-- OUTPUT is 'ARR ARR '
```

Comment: One condition is my SOxx1 col2 is ALLOW NULL, and SOxx2 col2 is NOT NULL
I also not sure how this will happen, but I just solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your columns are `CHAR` and not `VARCHAR`?

Nothing is stripping spaces after you get the result from SQL Server?

Can you try this:

```
declare @table1 table (id int, one char(4))
declare @table2 table (id int, one char(4))
insert into @table1 values (1 ,'ARR ')
insert into @table2 values (1 ,'ARR ')
select (isnull(a.one,'') + isnull(b.one,'')) AS WhatEver
from @table1 a left join @table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

I get, as expected,

> ARR ARR

Comment: Then I really dont understand what is happening..
Yah my data type is CHAR(4).

Comment: Are you executing your script in SSMS, or through another program?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different collations?

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.Columns1,'') collate Latin1_General_BIN + ISNULL(b.Columns1,'') collate Latin1_General_BIN AS WhatEver
FROM Table1 a 
left join Table2 b on a.Columns0 = b.Columns0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (ISNULL(a.Columns1,'') +ISNULL(b.Columns1,'')) AS WhatEver FROM Table1 a left join Table2 b on a.Columns0 = b.Columns0
```

Comment: do u have space end of the data?

Comment: OP is expecting the space to appear from his data: he has "`ARR `" + "`ARR `", and is expecting "`ARR ARR `".

Comment: oops .. sorry.. i'll check that. didnt see that space

Comment: by my understanding to CHAR data type is : empty space will be filled in if user input is less than data type configured.